# DrawBitmap placing bitmap in the wrong location

Tags: android, bitmap

I want to place a bitmap on top of another bitmap, I have done that with the method below. The bitmap is the current bitmap that will have another bitmap placed on top. Marker bitmap is the bitmap that is to be placed on top of the current bitmap. x and y are the locations of the tap, these are correct to my knowledge because the on tap listener does recognize the location but displays the bitmap in the wrong location.

```
public Bitmap drawOnToCanvas(Bitmap bitmap){


    float centerX = (x  - (markerBitmap.getWidth()/2));
    float centerY = (y + (markerBitmap.getHeight()/2));
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, new Matrix(), null);
    canvas.drawBitmap(markerBitmap, centerX , centerY, null);

    return bitmap;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem when you draw the bitmap for the current bitmap make sure you get the matrix and not just make a new matrix. Example fix is below:

```
public Bitmap drawOnToCanvas(Bitmap bitmap, Matrix currentMatrix){


float centerX = (x  - (markerBitmap.getWidth()/2));
float centerY = (y + (markerBitmap.getHeight()/2));
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, currentMatrix, null);
canvas.drawBitmap(markerBitmap, centerX , centerY, null);

return bitmap;

}
```